# Linux and Windows documentation

Tags: linux, windows

I've been wondering, but in the jungle of documentation book, if there is an editor in particular that publish, good, and easy to read book for Linux (RedHat, Suse, Centos), UNIX (Solaris), Windows. That can help me to gain more knowledge and be more effective in my work?

Book about Linux/Unix kernel, Windows/Linux network, RedHat certification lesson, and so on.

If I'm not really explicit please tell me, I will try to be more specific.

Thanks.

EDIT : I've been looking in the O'Reilly edition, there seem to be a lot of book, but not sure if these book will help me getting a better knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O'Reilly is considered among the better book series out there. The best thing to do, since this information can become dated quickly, is go to Amazon and read their reviews for books in the field that are less than one or two years old (the book publishing date, not the reviews.)

Answer (score 2):

Another useful publisher of technical books is Addison-Wesley. Bart's comments about finding good books apply here, too.

Comment: Don't know Addison-Wesley. Will check this too.